# Updating a record when found or create a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 7, with the following code, I look for a `user` with the passed `email` and return it if it exists. Otherwise, I create a new `user` with `email` and `role`.

```rb
User.create_with(role: params[:role]).find_or_create_by(email: params[:email])
```

Now, I need to find or create a `user` by the passed `email`. If it exists, I need to update the `role` if it's different from the one received as a parameter. For instance, assuming I have in the DB a `user`

```rb
{ role: "basic," email: "me@example.com" }
```

and I get

```rb
params = { role: "basic," email: "me@example.com" }
```

nothing has to be done. But, with a user

```rb
{ role: "admin", email: "me@example.com" }
```

and I get

```rb
params = { role: "basic", email: "me@example.com" }
```

the user must be updated with the `basic` role.

**Is there a way to achieve this without retrieving the `user` (as I did above when creating a `user`)?**

What came to mind is

```rb
User.find_or_create_by(email: params[:email]).update(role: params[:role])
```

which works but makes two writes, and `updated_at` is different from `created_at`

Comment: Rails will fire only 1 query update if exists or create a new one if not exists. Could you show the log of the queries?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to have a DB unique constraint on `email` and use `upsert_all`, but if you don't want to bother with that (or need to ensure callbacks are triggered) then there's no clever shortcut method, so simply:

```rb
User.find_or_initialize_by(email: params[:email]).update(role: params[:role])
```